# How to get span id value into excel VBA?

Tags: html, vba, excel

Ok so here is my entire code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With appIE
    .Navigate "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=" & "AAPL"
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Set getPrice = appIE.Document.getElementById("yfs_l84_aapl")
Dim myValue As String: myValue = getPrice.Cells(1).innerHTML

appIE.Quit
Set appIE = Nothing

Range("B1").Value = myValue

End Sub
```

And here is the HTML that I'm trying to read into Excel (specifically, I need the 113.92):

```
<span id="yfs_l84_aapl">113.92</span>
```

What do I have to change in these two lines of code to read a "span id"?

```
Set getPrice = appIE.Document.getElementById("yfs_l84_aapl")
Dim myValue As String: myValue = getPrice.Cells(1).innerHTML
```

Or, alternatively, is there a way just to read whatever is directly after "yfs_184"??

I'm brand new to coding and am working very hard to get better, so any help is really appreciated!! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
myValue = getPrice.innerText
```

Comment: That works... but only the first time I write the code and run it. I get an error msg every time I try to run it after that :/ Here's the updated lines of code:   

`Set getPrice = appIE.document.getElementById("yfs_l84_aapl") //
Dim myValue As String: myValue = getPrice.innerText`